# Was bedeutet "der Vollständigkeit halber"?

Tags: meaning

Ich habe den Satz in dem folgenden Text gefunden:

> Der Vollständigkeit halber soll es hier dennoch erwähnt werden

Ich würde den Satz als "The (halber) availability should be anyway warned" ins Englische übersetzen.

Wie kann ich in dem Kontext „halber“ übersetzen?

Comment: erwähnen = to mention, not to warn

Comment: Ich habe Zweifel ob availability=Vollständigkeit heißt und der englische Satz macht einen sehr seltsamen Eindruck auf mich. Davon abgesehen dass er nicht das aussagt was die deutsche Vorgabe aussagt.

Comment: [Entry on dict.cc](https://www.dict.cc/?s=der+vollst%C3%A4ndigkeit+halber)

Comment: "halber" == "wegen", except that it functions as a *post*position.

Comment: _Wegen_ can be used as a postposition as well; in fact, you could say _der Vollständigkeit wegen_, although it would be (just slightly, for me) less idiomatic here.

Comment: Please note that this website is not a substitute to copy pasting or typing the word in any online dictionary. E.g. https://www.dwds.de/wb/halber

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Der Ausdruck [Der Vollständigkeit halber](https://www.redensarten-index.de/suche.php?suchbegriff=~~der%20Vollst%C3%A4ndigkeit%20halber&suchspalte%5B%5D=rart_ou) ist ein feststehender Ausdruck und bedeutet soviel wie

> Um wirklich alle Aspekte [eines Umstands/Sache/Ereignis/etc] erwähnt zu haben

Normalerweise kann er als

> For the sake of completeness

übersetzt werden.

Alternativen findet man in [diesem Thread](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/446600/alternatives-for-for-the-sake-of-completeness), u.a.

> To cover every aspect

Comment: "der Fairness halber" dürfte relativ neu, also noch produktiv sein, "allenthalb" dagegen relativ alt. Von einem feststehenden Ausdruck zu reden, der also kaum weiter analysiert werden kann, hilft niemandem wirklich weiter, obwohl es auch nicht ganz unwahr erscheint. Vgl der Einfachkeit halber Englisch *on behalf of*. Weiter helfen kann ich leider nicht.

Answer (score -1):

Um die mögliche Etymologie besser zu verstehen, könnte es wie folgt umformuliert werden:

*„die Hälfte der Gründe, warum wir das überhaupt machen ist die Vollstängigkeit“*

Comment: Im "Grund, warum" wird die Bedeutung des "halber" transportiert, nicht in "die Hälfte". Das wirkt alles andere als plausibel auf mich. Mögliche Etymologien sollte man nicht aus dem Stehgreif erfinden.

Comment: Ich verstehe nicht was deine Antwort aussagt, oder wie sie die Frage beantwortet.

Comment: Das ist ein guter Punkt und verdient es nicht runtergewertet zu werden, @cardamom. Im oben geposteten Link wird auch auf eine eventuelle Verwandtschaft mit "halb" hingewiesen, und daß der Ausdruck etwas bedeuten kann was nicht unbedingt notwendig wäre aber nun eben mal gemacht wird.

Comment: Es wäre ein guter Punkt, wenn es stimmen würde oder zumindest triftige Gründe dafür sprechen würden. Wie es aussieht, ist es aber eher ins Blaue spekuliert und darüber hinaus wohl auch falsch. "halber" kommt wohl von "Hälfte", aber lt. Duden im Sinne von "Seite". D.h.die ursprüngliche Bedeutung ist "von dieser Seite aus betrachtet" / "unter diesem Aspekt betrachtet"

Comment: @RHa Gibt es denn da keinen Link der diese deine Interpretation stützen würde ? https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/_halber und https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/halber_aufgrund_fuer_wegen  Duden sagt auch hier althd. Hälfte = Seite. Cardamons Post ist also durchaus gültig und wie ich meine, sprachlich und etymologisch richtig.

Comment: @a_donda Hälfte = Seite ist aber etwas anderes als "Die Hälfte der Gründe, weswegen..."

Comment: Das denke ich nicht. Von dieser Seite aus betrachet wird es eben gemacht (eine Hälfte) ... und von der anderen halte ich es für unnötig (andere Hälfte). Das bedeutet auch der Duden Eintrag, imo. Ursprünglich: Hälfte, abgeleitet: Seite. Paßt perfekt ...

Comment: @a_donda: Nein. Die Hälfte der Gründe, das wären bei 4 Gründen 2, aus denen es getan wird. Gründe es nicht zu tun ist etwas anderes als andere, weitere Gründe, etwas zu tun, die von einer anderen Seite kommen. "Hälfte" und "Seite" bringt cardamon überhaupt nicht in einen Zusammenhang. "Seite" wird gar nicht erwähnt, "Hälfte" wird im heutigen Sinne gedeutet und das ist falsch.

Answer (score -2):

**Halber** bedeutet **wegen, Vollständigkeit completeness**.

It should be mentioned because of completeness.